# word-database integration in Rational RequistePro

Tags: ibm-rational

How to integrate word document with Rational RequistePro.
          If i have document with 50 requirements and i want to put that word document in reqpro, will it generate those 50 requirements.If it does, how can i do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to d it using the "import document" feature of RequisitePro. It allows you to import your requirements using a mix of three kinds of parsing:

- Delimiters: Your requirements are delimited by two strings in your document, for example: [[This is a requirement]]. "[[" and "]]" would be your delimiters.
- Keywords: All your requirements have a keyword that identifies them as requirements. It is a common practice to use keywords as "shall" (The system shall...) in the requirements definition. This option allows you to find your requirement by providing the keywords to use.
- Word styles: If your document uses a specific style to identify the requirements you can tell ReqisitePro to use that style to find your requirements.

To import a document go to File > Import.. choose Word document and follow the wizard. You will be able to either import the requirements AND the document or just the requirements (or just the document, but I'm clear that's not something yo want.)